# Get Google contacts via AuthSub c#

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api, authsub

Does any one have a working example of getting google contact via AuthSub in c#

I have tried this [url](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#auth_sub) , but i was not able to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code from one of my projects:

```
    public class GoogleContactsProvider : IContactProvider
{
    #region IContactProvider Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the contacts list form the contact provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public EntityCollection<IContactItem> GetContactsList()
    {
        EntityCollection<IContactItem> collection = new EntityCollection<IContactItem>();

        // Setup the contacts request (autopage true returns all contacts)
        RequestSettings requestSettings = new RequestSettings("AgileMe", UserName, Password);
        requestSettings.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest contactsRequest = new ContactsRequest(requestSettings);

        // Get the feed
        Feed<Contact> feed = contactsRequest.GetContacts();

        // create our collection by looping through the feed
        foreach (Contact contact in feed.Entries)
        {
            GoogleContactItem newContact = new GoogleContactItem();
            newContact.Name = contact.PrimaryEmail.Address;
            newContact.Summary = contact.Summary;

            collection.Add(newContact);
        }

        return collection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the user for the contact provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the user.</value>
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the password for the contact provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The password.</value>
    public string Password { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

EntityCollection is a wrapper around a simple List and GoogleContactItem is a wrapper around the retrieved information.

Comment: @Perry, I am trying a similar one to stackoverflow login, where i will be redirect to gmail to enter password, but here i am using to get the Address book. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I am not sure I this was your answer or if you try to do something else? Can you explain further?

Comment: What is GoogleContactItem, IContactProvider, .. ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this example so simple. [link](http://www.dotnetethics.com/2008/09/signin-using-google-account.html)
And it works great.

Comment: OAuth 1.0 deprecated ? any new sample using OAuth 2.0 ?